# How to use Akamai Netsession interface with firefox and other apps?

Tags: networking, internet, download

I have Akamai Net session Interface Installed on my laptop but I don't know how to use to by integrating it in Mozilla Firefox and other apps for downloading purpose. How Can i do it? Plz provide a detailed instruction.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, you shouldn't need to do anything specific. It should be integrated into your network stack.

According to [Akamai's FAQ](https://www.akamai.com/uk/en/solutions/products/media-delivery/netsession-interface-faq.jsp)

> ### How can I see what it does and control its activity?
>
> NetSession provides a console that gives you the ability to review your NetSession activity and manage settings.
>
> On Windows, open your Windows Control Panel, then click the icon or link to the Akamai NetSession Interface Control Panel.
>
> On Mac OS X, the Akamai extension icon is found under Other --> Akamai on the System Preferences pane.
>
> ### I'm having some trouble downloading or streaming? What should I do?
>
> If your problem turns out to be a simple one, you may resolve it by running a troubleshooting report that NetSession provides. You can run the troubleshooter as follows:
>
> Open the NetSession Control Panel / System Preferences as described above.
>
> Choose the Support tab in the NetSession Control Panel and run the Troubleshooting Report. As the report is generated, it will tell you if it finds any simple problems occurring.
>
> If that doesn't resolve your issue, select the Applications tab in the Control Panel and contact the Customer Support for the application you were attempting to download or stream.

You might also want to read [What is Akamai NetSession Client?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-security/what-is-akamai-netsession-client/6c85ea38-e236-42b4-8c02-ea425d5658dc?auth=1) and decide for yourself if the security concerns are credible.